# module 'thinc' has no attribute 'layers'

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, textacy

I am following [this](https://realpython.com/natural-language-processing-spacy-python/) article for my work and in this article, under heading `Verb Phrase Detection`, I am following the instructions but after successfully installing the `textacy` library (It shows in `pip list`) when I use `import textacy` in jupyter notebook, it gives the following Attribute Error:

```
AttributeError: module 'thinc' has no attribute 'layers'
```

Can anyone please tell me how to resolve this error. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

pip install thinc

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).